# Store a 2-D string array but display a 1-D string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm a relatively new student to C# programming and I'm having a lot of trouble with 2-D arrays. In this program the user is supposed to input names, verbs, and objects for an insult generator, but the problem is that I have to pointlessly store them all in one 2-D string array and generate the insults in a 1-D string array and I'm just completely lost. Can I store name, verb, and object into a single 2-D string array? Any help would be appreciated.

My issue is with initializing and storing the 2D string array and then converting to the 1D array.

```
 private static void Generate(int insultnum, int sentnum)
    {
        int Ncounter = 1;
        int Vcounter = 1;
        int Ocounter = 1;
        string[,] name = new string[sentnum,?];
        string[,] verb = new string[sentnum,?];
        string[,] insult = new string[sentnum,?];
        do 
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter name of #{0}: ", Ncounter);
            //length and height 2D array for loop text is just a placeholder from an earlier project
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                  name[Ncounter - 1, ??] = Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
            //
            Ncounter++;
        } while (Ncounter < sentnum);
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter name of #{0}: ", Vcounter);
            verb[Vcounter-1, ?] = Console.ReadLine();
            //2D array loop text
            Vcounter++;

        } while (Vcounter < sentnum);
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter name of #{0}: ", Ocounter);
            insult[Ocounter-1, ?] = Console.ReadLine();
            //2D array loop text
            Ocounter++;

        } while (Ocounter < sentnum);
        Ncounter = 0;
        Vcounter = 0;
        Ocounter = 0;
        string[] insults = new string[insultnum];
        //insults = name[?,?] + " " + verb[?,?] + " " + object[?,?];
    }
```

**Example Output:**

> Enter the number of insults to generate: 3
> Enter the number of names, verbs, and objects: 3
> Please enter name #1: Bob
> Please enter name #2: Rhys
> Please enter name #3: Kaa
> Please enter verb #1: licks
> Please enter verb #2: touches
> Please enter verb #3: tastes
> Please enter object #1: dirt
> Please enter object #2: cars
> Please enter object #3: asphalt
> Insults have been generated
>
> Kaa licks dirt
> Bob tastes asphalt
> Bob licks cars

Comment: Why are you using 2D arrays?

Comment: because literally no other reason than my teacher told me to.

Answer (score 0):

*2D array* i.e. `string[,]` is a bit *strange collection* to store the data, since it requires that

```
 NameCounter == VerbCounter == ObjectCounter
```

More natural choice is a *jagged* array `string[][]` which allows *arbitrary* `NameCounter`, `VerbCounter`, `ObjectCounter`. And, please, *decompose* your solution, split it to number of *easy* to implement and test methods:

```
 // Random generator for insulting
 private Random rgen = new Random();

 // 1st index - category (name/verb/insult), 2nd index item within category
 private static string[,] data;

 private static string[] categories = new string[] {
   "name", "verb", "insult", 
 }; 

 // Input single categore, e.g. Names or Verbs 
 private static void InputCategory(int category) {
   for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(1); ++i) {
     Console.Write($"Please enter {categories[category]} #{i + 1}: ");
     data[category, i] = Console.ReadLine();
   }         
 }

 // Input all categories 
 private static void InputData() {
   Console.Write($"Enter the number of names, verbs, and objects: ");

   // simplest; more accurate implementation uses int.TryParse()
   int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   data = new string[categories.Length, n];

   foreach(var int i = 0; i < categories.Length; ++i) 
     InputCategory();
 }
```

To write an insult generator you should combine *random* items from each category

```
 private static string[] Insults(int count) {
   string[] result = new string[count];  

   // take count times a item from each category   
   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder

     for (int c = 0; c < categories.Length; ++c) {
       if (c > 0)
         sb.Append(' ');

       sb.Append(data[c, rgen.Next(data.GetLength(1))]);  
     }

     result[i] = sb.ToString();
   } 

   return ressult; 
 }
```

Having these methods you can put easily

```
 private static void Main() {
   int numberOfInsults = ....

   InputData();

   foreach (var insult in Insults(numberOfInsults))
     Console.Write(insult);

   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply! I see that you simply think of the 2-D array like a graph and go from there. We haven't gotten far enough for stringbuilder but thank you very much